# Angular services: How to use returned resource object's data in another controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been struggling with this for a while now and have not been able to find an appropriate answer for the following.

There is an angular `Address` service.

**services.js**

```
appServices.factory('Address', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('addresses/:uuid.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{ uuid:'addresses' }, isArray: false}
    });
  }
]);
```

The service is used to retrieve the longitude and latitude of a given address and attaches both to the scope:

**controllers.js**

```
var addressGeo = Address.get( {uuid: $routeParams.uuid},
    function(data)
    { 
        $scope.address = data.response.address;
        $scope.Lat = data.response.address.geoCoord.lat;
        $scope.Lon = data.response.address.geoCoord.lon;
    }
);
```

Both values shall then be passed to another function in the controller in order to create a GeoJson object, however, they appear as undefined. As expected, I can bind them to the view displaying the respective values.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I'm going to guess that your problem is that your success callback in your `Address.get()` call is asynchronous.  And as such, you can't access `$scope.Lat` or `$scope.Lon` until after that ajax call has returned.  Before that, the values will be undefined...

Comment: I believe you are right, cause if I put my function to which the two variables a forwarded to within the scope of the callback, it does work. Now, I am wondering if it is possible to separate both so that I will not have everything wrapped within a very long service call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tennisgent pointed out in his comment, this is an issue with the asynchronous `get()` call not being resolved when you try to access the two properties on the scope.

If you don't want to put your other code into the callback passed to `get()`, use a deferred using `$q`:

```
var addressDeferred = $q.defer();

var addressGeo = Address.get( {uuid: $routeParams.uuid},
    function(data)
    { 
        $scope.address = data.response.address;
        $scope.Lat = data.response.address.geoCoord.lat;
        $scope.Lon = data.response.address.geoCoord.lon;
        addressDeferred.resolve( data.response.address );
    }
);

addressDeferred.promise.then( function( address ) {
  // Do something with address
} );
```